# Hide the tab bar in a tab bar application

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a new project from the template:

IPhoneOS>Application>Tab Bar Application.

I get two tabs.

How can I make the second become a full screen hiding the tab bar and even the status bar?

I tried to check the "Wants Full screen" - but it didn't help.

(Much less important... When I do get a full screen I do I get back?)

Please give me a simple code/guidelines or a reference to them, cause I'm a beginner - and Me and the compiler got too many issues to make things worse

Thanks 
Asaf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141766/91458

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To hide the tab bar you can use **hidesBottomBarWhenPushed**. For instance:

```
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc]init]; 
myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
[myController release];
```

To hide the status bar you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

To hide the nav bar you can use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: myController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
works when I move from a table view to the view...

Is it possible to load the first view (of the tab bar) without showing the bar... where do I put the code?

Answer (score 20):

You can just use:

```
//Navigation bar:
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

//Statusbar:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

//Tabbar:
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: In case you're using tabbar with navigation controller `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` will not work, but `tabBarController.tabBar.hidden` will do.

Comment: I'm having trouble hiding the bottom bar when using RBStoryboardLink. Neither approach seems to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Modal View Controllers out?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Try the presentModalViewController:animated: method on your navigationController (instead of pushing a view controller)

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:foo animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm building a simple game at the main view and the setting grouped in the rest of the tab bar ... It's really hard for me to understand the navigation here... so building a tab bar in a modal view... if possible... seems too hard at the moment

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is by making the UITabBarController the rootViewController of a UINavigationController.  Then when you pushViewControllerAnimated: the tab bar will slide away with the root view controller.