# How to hide/show tab bar of a view with a navigation bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have views with a navigation bar and a tab bar. What I would like to happen is to hide the tab bar on a certain view and show the tab bar again when the user changes views.

I saw a snippet of code for hiding the tab bar:

```
-(void)makeTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hide
{
    // Custom code to hide TabBar
    if ( [tabBarController.view.subviews count] < 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    UIView *contentView;

    if ( [[tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] ) {
        contentView = [tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    } else {
        contentView = [tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (hide) {
        contentView.frame = tabBarController.view.bounds;       
    }
    else {
        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(tabBarController.view.bounds.origin.x,
             tabBarController.view.bounds.origin.y,
             tabBarController.view.bounds.size.width,
             tabBarController.view.bounds.size.height - tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);
    }

    tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = hide;
}
```

from: http://nickwaynik.com/iphone/hide-tabbar-in-an-ios-app/

I call this on the view wherein I want the tab bar hidden

```
[self makeTabBarHidden:YES];
```

it works fine when i show/hide it on that view but when I navigate back to the previous view, the tab bar there is also hidden. I tried calling that function in the view's `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidDisappear` functions but nothing happens. The same is true when the function is called in the previous view's `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` functions.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can set the UIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed instead:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];    
[detailViewController release];
```

Comment: Here's a cool looking solution in the case where pushing a new controller isn't an option, that should animate the bar in and out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller/11490623#11490623

Comment: That was great. Thank you so much. Just to let you know you could do that in prepareForSegue as well.

Comment: One thing to note is that the location of the set is important. Setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the location as shown in the answer works, but if setting it within DetailViewController's `viewDidLoad` method doesn't.

Answer (score 36):

You can also do this in the Interface Builder for a storyboard. Select the View Controller that you want to hide the Tab Bar for and then select "Hide Bottom Bar on Push".

[image]

Comment: the most elegant way in the answers

Answer (score 13):

I just created a category on UITabBarController that allows you to hide the TabBar, optionally with an animation:

https://github.com/idevsoftware/Cocoa-Touch-Additions/tree/master/UITabBarController_setHidden

It adds the `tabBarHidden` property (with `isTabBarHidden` as its getter) and the `- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` method.

Comment: Would be awesome if the landscape mode fix could get itself checked in. Maybe send a pull request with it, @boliva?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:
Set tab bar to hide in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for hide / show:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

Add this line to your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`; this will hide you tab from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The same property is available on the attributes inspector when you click on your view controller on your Xib or storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code but `tabBar` remains hidden when you navigate back.

```
    //hide tabbar
    //self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

**better way** is to do through main.storyboard
check `"Hide Bottom Bar on Push"` as I've done.

[image]