# Hide bottom bar on demand

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController. I'm presenting a sort of popover view using a semi-transparent UIView, but am not calling `presentModalViewController` or any of the usual methods. I know about `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`, but is there a way I can hide the bottom bar (or even betterm slide it out) on demand (just before my subView is added to the navigationController's top view)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried setting this property?

```
navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

Or with animation:

```
[navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Excellent. I thought UIToolbars were generally placed at the top but this seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: This hides and shows a bottom toolbar, but does not affect the tab bar. So, according to me it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true`

Answer (score 0):

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141766/305351 to related question.

Specifically [Borut Tomazin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384864/borut-tomazin)'s comment and his solution https://gist.github.com/borut-t/6507423.