# Safe way to remove tab bar from UITabBarController in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use UITabBarController but I do not need a tab bar because I'm going to switch tabs from the menu in another view controller. I want to remove it as it will be never used. I've created a subclass of UITabBarController and put this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tabBar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Is that safe to remove tab bar that way?

Update: **Why tab bar controller?**

Apple suggests to use standard container view controllers whenever it possible. I'm trying to follow that. My screens workflow is the same as for tabs, except that they are switched by left side menu, not by the tab bar.

When I use a UIViewController and change it's child view controller I've got a lot of problems when autolayouts are not working properly.

The other reason is that I want to use story board, rather then create segues from the code so I can see my app workflow easily.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use a tab bar controller?

Comment: You can just use a UIViewController and change it's child view controller when you want to switch views.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've updated my question explaining why I'm trying to use tab bar controller

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7524054/210171

Comment: tabBar.hidden = YES has worked perfectly. It hides bar forever and constraints all work in both landscape and portrait mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are saying, you don't want to use it, then why to remove it. You can go with a 
`tabbarcontroller` with hidden `tabbar`. I am switching tabs from the bottom custom bar.

I am doing an app, which has a tababr controller with three items. Instead of using system tab, I am creating a custom view at the footer like tab & have actually set the `hidden` property of tabbarController's tabbar to YES.

```
myTabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
[app.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
[app.tabbarcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
[app.window addSubview:app.navigationController.view];
[app.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```