# Hide TabBar and show NavigationController toolbar on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following view hierarchy:

Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Custom View Controller

In my Custom View I want the TabBar to disappear and show a toolbar instead. Much like in iOS7  native photos app when pressing 'select'.

I tried different solutions I found of SO but managed to get either:

1. TabBar hidden and Toolbar shown with black gap
2. TabBar hidden and Toolbar hidden
3. TabBar hidden Toolbar shown with gap from bottom. However, Custom view content reaches the bottom of the screen (under the toolbar and in the same place the tab bar used to be)

The difference from other solutions I found is that I need this to happen on click and not on push.

Some of the things I tried:

```
// #1
[self.navigationController.toolbar setHidden:!isSelecting];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:isSelecting];

// #2
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

// #3
#1 & #2 variants @ different controller along the path
```

Comment: "The difference from other solutions I found is that I need this to happen on click and not on push." Umm... what?

Comment: Can you share some code or screenshots of what you achieved? Did you try resizing the view of your custom view controller to fill the black gap that you got?

Comment: I suspect the Photos app is doing a modal presentation (with no animation) when you touch the "select" button. If you present a controller that has a toolbar, it would cover the tab bar, and give the look you see in Photos.

Comment: @LordZsolt, I mean that I think that answers that suggested using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` won't work in this case. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @NikolasBurk, I didn't try resizing. Added some code.

Comment: @rdelmar, But it seems that the 'new' view preserves the same state as before pressing select. Is this doable with a modal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually, after playing with the settings I managed to make it work. I'm not sure why it works now and didn't work before so I'd appreciate your comments.

**Storyboard:**

1. Mark as checked "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" for the Custom View Controller
2. Mark as checked "Show Toolbar" for the Navigation Controller

**Code:**

On button click hide/unhide tabBar: `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:state]`

This almost works. It does hide/unhide the tabBar when pressing the button but the only problem is that the tabBar is initially hidden when switching tabs. I had to do some extra effort to have it visible.

Set `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to unhide tabBar when switching tabs. I did it in a custom `SUSourceTabController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:   (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

We also need to unhide it for the first tab view in the Custom View Controller code. Using `setHidden:NO` in any other place in the code didn't work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Ah, it really helped me. But, for me, setting "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" to true was just enough. Thanks!

Comment: The only answer that finally got me what I wanted. Need to have a table VC controller in one tab have an "Edit" option. Edit mode allows multiple selection. I need to hide the tab bar and show a toolbar. I'm using iOS 9 and toggling the tabBar and toolbar states was easy enough (I did the same was as OP). This answer showed how to prevent the tabBar from hiding when switching tabs. Also, I didn't need to do the second part ("unhide it for the first tab view") because I was using the second tab as the starting tab (using selectedIndex = 1 in the viewDidLoad of custom TabController)

Comment: Can not remove the gap (xcode 8, iOS 8.2). To fix the issue, have to use another toolbar instead of self.navigationController.toolbar, and add a constraint 'Bottom Space to Superview = 0' instead of to Bottom Layout Guide.

Comment: It doesn't look as expected on iPhone X if you constraint bottom to superview instead of layout guide  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236375/custom-uitoolbar-too-close-to-the-home-indicator-on-iphone-x

Comment: Implemented @Xyand's solution and works properly on iPhone X.

Comment: Are you not facing any issues on iOS13? I'm facing animation issues while transitioning from tab-bar to toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Check this category from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383069/how-to-hide-show-tab-bar-of-a-view-with-a-navigation-bar-in-ios)'s answer.

UITabBarController+HideTabbar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITabBarController (HideTabbar)
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

UITabBarController+HideTabbar.m

```
#import "UITabBarController+HideTabbar.h"
#define kAnimationDuration .3
@implementation UITabBarController (HideTabbar)

- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    }
    if (!hidden) {
        fHeight -= self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    }
    CGFloat animationDuration = animated ? kAnimationDuration : 0.f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews){
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            }
            else {
                if (hidden) {
                    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
                }
            }
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (!hidden){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
                for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
                    if (![view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
                        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```